# How to create OneNote page on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, onenote

Can I create a OneNote page or can I make a call to just open OneNote from a button in a Mobile Phone 8.1 app? I am using Visual Studio 2013 with the Phone 8.1 addin

Looks like you have to authenticate using the API and it writes to the cloud. Only need local access to OneNote on the device. App will be used in areas where OneDrive access will not be available to write to.

Answer (score 0):

All OneNote notebooks and pages on WP are already stored on OneDrive (or Sharepoint & OneDrive for Business). There is no "local" notebooks on WP.

Our APIs are only web-APIs that support creating pages on OneDrive and require Microsoft Account authentication.